# What packages are needed for German spell-check support in LO Writer 5.0.4.2?

Tags: libreoffice, spell-checking

I installed LibreOffice Writer 5.0.4.2 along with the following packages:

```
hunspell-de-de
myspell-de-de
aspell-de
```

They all do not, however, provide me with German spell check support. What other package is needed?

[image]

Comment: http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/german-de-de-frami-dictionaries (?)

Comment: LO5 is not mentioned as a compatible release.

Comment: Curiously I have `hunspell-de-de` installed and none of the other packages you mention, yet I have German spell checking available in LibreOffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `libreoffice-l10n-de`, but I'm unsure whether this is just the language of the app itself, and not its dictionaries.

I've just peeked in my personal `install-fresh-ubuntu-desktop.sh` script and I can see that I include a few more packages than you mentioned (I also install for a more languages, but you can ignore that).  I don't know if this will help you:

```
for x in da en-gb de; do
  sudo apt-get --yes install aspell-$x
done


for x in da en-us de; do
  sudo apt-get --yes install myspell-$x
done

for x in da en-us de-de; do
  sudo apt-get --yes install hunspell-$x
done


for x in en-us en-gb de; do
  sudo apt-get --yes install hyphen-$x
done

for x in en-us de; do
  sudo apt-get --yes install mythes-$x 
done

for x in danish british american ngerman; do
  sudo apt-get --yes install w$x
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this extension:

Here is [link to sources of German Dictionary](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/german-de-de-frami-dictionaries) for Libreoffice.

Click [here for the dictionary file](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/german-de-de-frami-dictionaries/releases/2015.12.28/dict-de_de-frami_2015-12-28.oxt) for downloading the file.

Click [here](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/HowTo/install_extension) to see how to install extensions in Libreoffice.

You may also try setting the language default for German:

[image: Extras menu in Libreoffice]

[image: Language choose window]

I hope these help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. First download German Dictionary from [extensions.libreoffice.org](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/german-de-de-frami-dictionaries). And then open your LibreOffice Writer and go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> -> <kbd>Extension Manager</kbd>:

[image]

Then click on <kbd>Add</kbd> and select your downloaded [German Dictionary](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/german-de-de-frami-dictionaries/releases/2015.12.28/dict-de_de-frami_2015-12-28.oxt). Thats all.

Viel Erfolg.